# I am confused about the stability of carbanion III and IV in the image

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, stability

[image: Finding order of stability of 4 carbanions using resonance and inductive effects]

I am confused about the stability of carbanion III and IV in the image, I think III is more unstable because of electron donating effect (+R) of  $\ce{-OCH3}$ group but my book says III is more stable than IV. In compound III, $\ce{-OCH3}$ would donate its lone pair and would make the carbanion unstable but no such effect happens in compound IV. $\ce{-OCH3}$ in compound III would also have -I effect to stabilize the carbanion but I have read that for $\ce{-OR}$ group, +R effect is more than its -I effect i.e., its electron donating nature is more than its electron withdrawing nature through inductive effect, +R means electron donating by resonance (In $\ce{-OR}$, $\ce{R}$ is any alkyl group)

Comment: To answer this question, I have been trying to find the pKa values of the four parent acids, but I have only found acetone. It is the only compound of the four listed in the well known [Bordwell](http://www.chem.wisc.edu/areas/reich/pkatable/) and [Evans](http://evans.rc.fas.harvard.edu/pdf/evans_pKa_table.pdf) tables. Ethyl acetate (not methyl) is listed, so I supposed that could be used, but I cannot find an authoritative source for acetaldehyde and methyl vinyl ketone. I am frustrated by my inability to easily search for papers that report pKa values.

Comment: The picture clearly says that it is abput resonance stability. So drawing all possible resonance structures for every substance should help probably.

Answer (score 1):

I think in 3, carbanion is resonance stabilised. While in 4, C=C-C=O are in conjugation, thus will not stabilise carbanion.

Comment: Why does conjugation prevent stabilisation? I see no reason for this.

Answer (score 1):

I think in both (III) and (IV), **Cross Conjugation** is present which generally prevents resonance from taking place.

- In (III), Both CH3O and CH2**minus** can give electrons to the C in middle.
- In (IV), After resonance, CH**minus**(on left) and CH2**minus**(on right), can give electrons to the C in middle.

Supposedly, in (III), O will not prefer to give it's LP electrons because of high Electronegativity. 
In (IV), CH**minus**(on left) can comparatively give electrons more easily than O. 
Also +M effect of CH2**minus** is greater than O(with LP).

Therefore, CROSS CONJUGATION EXTENT in (III) is less than in (IV).

Hence, (III) is more stable than (IV).